# Retrofit: Blank screen appears in android studio at irregular intervals getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit

I am using retrofit for parsing. I am not sure what is happening, but all of a sudden blank screen appears while fetching data from server.And it is not regular, sometimes it appears or sometimes not. And moreover is not limited to a single page, I mean it is happening in any of the activity where I am using services.And after pressing back button once or twice, listing appears. 
After debugging I found it goes on onFailure method of retrofit and gives a 
**`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`** Do any one of you know the reason? Your kind support will truly be appreciated.
 This is my code:

```
GridView mLvCategories;
CustomCategoriesAdapter adapter;
private GetCustomCategoriesModel[] mArray;
ImageView viewImage;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_professional_list);
    initializeWidgets();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items); // load
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);// load icons from
    set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
    callToGetAllCategories();

}

private void initializeWidgets() {
    mLvCategories=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_categories);
}

private void callToGetAllCategories() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProfessionalListActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");
    RestClient.GitApiInterface service = RestClient.getClient();
    String url="http://scorpioinfotech.net/demo/api/get_categories";
    Call<GetCustomCategoriesModel[]> call = service.hitGetApi(url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetCustomCategoriesModel[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<GetCustomCategoriesModel[]> response) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                // request successful (status code 200, 201)
                GetCustomCategoriesModel[] result = response.body();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "response = " + new Gson().toJson(result));
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    mArray = result;
                    adapter = new CustomCategoriesAdapter(ProfessionalListActivity.this, mArray);
                    mLvCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mLvCategories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Intent mIntent = new Intent(ProfessionalListActivity.this, SubListProActivity.class);
                            mIntent.putExtra("sub_id", mArray[position].getCategory_id() + "");
                            startActivity(mIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                // response received but request not successful (like 400,401,403 etc)
                //Handle errors
                Toast.makeText(ProfessionalListActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("ProfessionalListActivity", "Response is not success");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("ProfessionalListActivity", "On Failure");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (LogInActivity.userLoginViaFb) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfessionalListActivity.this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.find_pro);
        builder.setTitle("Find Pro").setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Please help.

Edit:

```
public class RestClient {


    private static GitApiInterface gitApiInterface ;
    public static String baseUrl = "http://scorpioinfotech.net/demo" ;
    public static GitApiInterface getClient() {
        if (gitApiInterface == null) {

            OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return response;
                }
            });

            Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverter(String.class, new ToStringConverter())
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            gitApiInterface = client.create(GitApiInterface.class);
        }
        return gitApiInterface ;
    }

    public interface GitApiInterface {

        @GET
        Call<GetCustomCategoriesModel[]> hitGetApi(@Url String url);

        @GET
        Call<Lister[]> hitGetIntroApi (@Url String url);

        @GET
        Call<GetProDetailInfoModel> hitGetDetailinfoApi (@Url String url);

        @GET
        Call<Reviews[]> hitGetFeedbackApi (@Url String url);



    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using synchronous calls ?

Comment: Mostly when you start your app it happen bcoz retrofit first call takes time after that it smooth ...... do one thing just use progress bar till your data not updated .

Comment: I am using progress dialog also. But it gets stopped and after some time screen gets blank

Comment: you mean crash the app ?

Comment: no app didn't crash only blank screen appears

Comment: just do one thing in your **android studio** in the **Android Monitor** just select **Log level** is ERROR and **No filters** and run you got your error .

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas if you are using synchronous calls then a blank screen will appear because the main thread has to wait till the response is fetched. This will result in white screen, seems like the most probable reason.  !!

Comment: @varun how can  i resolve this then?

Comment: For long operations synchronous is not the way to go, you should use asynchronous calls but first you need to confirm if you are really using synchronous calls, can you post your retrofit class code, where you defiend the interfaces and all

Comment: I have edited. Please check

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas well u are already using asynchronous !! Must be some other issue, let me see !!

Comment: Yes please, its been so long that i can't fix this one.The response comes in milliseconds when check through link but in app it takes too long.No idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110880/discussion-between-varunkr-and-priyanka-minhas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally no more blank screen appears. I just add these two lines, as time out exception was coming:
public class RestClient {

```
 private static GitApiInterface gitApiInterface ;
    public static String baseUrl = "http://scorpioinfotech.net/demo" ;
    public static GitApiInterface getClient() {
        if (gitApiInterface == null) {
            OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

            okClient.setReadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // added
            okClient.setConnectTimeout(300,TimeUnit.MINUTES); //added

            okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return response;
                }
            });

            Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverter(String.class, new ToStringConverter())
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            gitApiInterface = client.create(GitApiInterface.class);
        }
        return gitApiInterface ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you are loading images into your adapter from the web without scaling them which is a very costly and resource intensive operation. You should try scaling them and then setting the images. Blank screen is because too much work is being done on the UI thread.

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas can you please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem !!

Comment: again white screen issue

Comment: Oh, strange !! is it for long ?

Comment: yes i need to press the back button of the device then again goes to the activity for fetching details